# How to give a fixed height to a d3js sankey chart left side nodes

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I am working in this d3 sankey chart where I wanted to give a fixed height to left side node inorder to align sankey chart with donut chart.
The Green line represents separation between two charts and I need to fix the height of node next to donut chart
[image]

```
let data =
    {
      "links": [
        { "source": "Agriculture", "target": "Rice Cultivation", "value": "120" },
        { "source": "Agriculture", "target": "Deforestation", "value": "30" },
        { "source": "Agriculture", "target": "Coal Mining", "value": "30" },
        { "source": "Chemicals", "target": "HFCs - PFCs", "value": "100" },
        { "source": "Chemicals", "target": "HFCs - PFCs", "value": "50" }
],

"nodes":[

        { "name": "Agriculture" },
        { "name": "Chemicals" }
]
}
```

Comment: can you attach the data you are passing to d3.sankey()

Comment: updated please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Process your data convert all values into %
Ex: For Agriculture you have 120, 30, 30, total will be 180. Now, change values to % by dividing 120/180, 30/180, 30/180. Hence agriculture will be 100% when you sum it's targets

Repeat for all the groups you have, so your source should be equal to 100% when sum up, so heights of your source (left nodes) will be equal

```
let data = {
      "links": [
        { "source": "Agriculture", "target": "Rice Cultivation", "value": "66.67" },
        { "source": "Agriculture", "target": "Deforestation", "value": "16.67" },
        { "source": "Agriculture", "target": "Coal Mining", "value": "16.67" },
        { "source": "Chemicals", "target": "HFCs - PFCs", "value": "66.67" },
        { "source": "Chemicals", "target": "HFCs - PFCs", "value": "33.33" }
    ],
    "nodes":[
        { "name": "Agriculture" },
        { "name": "Chemicals" }
    ]
}
```

I hope u find it helpful, Thanks